# webview_flutter twitter widget using data/html not loading - Balnk space displaying?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, webview

I am using webview_flutter 2.0.4 in flutter application and trying to load twitter widget in this app. Its working in android platform and not loading in iOS devices. Tried different solutions but its not solved. How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe check the debug log for relevant errors, and attach them to the question

Comment: NO error logs! its showing only white widget..